# Loading html files in js files

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jsdom

I have this text.html file in my C:\Users\project\text.html and I want to load it in a testing file .js.

I want to load the HTML file in one of my functions of testing, so I can test HTML elements. When I put the html content inside the testing file like this it works well:

```html
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
...
 Then('...', function() {
     
 const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><div id="hey" class="modal-footer">Hello world</div>`);

});
```

But I do not want innerHTML, I want to load the file text.html from JSDOM and not writing the html inside my testing file. Is theer any way to do something like require text.html inide JSDOM??

Comment: if you're using node that better solution is using `fs.readFile` or `fs.readFileSync` to get content of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSDOM provides a [`fromFile`](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#fromfile) utility function that allows loading from a local file. This will load `./foo.html`.

```
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");

JSDOM.fromFile("./foo.html").then(dom => {
  // ...
});
```

If you need to load from a URL, there's also [`fromURL`](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#fromurl):

```
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");

JSDOM.fromURL("http://www.example.com/").then(dom => {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: The same thing you would do with `dom` when you do `const dom = new JSDOM(...`.

Comment: Ihave the testing function and I put the cons inside my test function and use it. So you mean to put the JSDOM.fromFile("http://www.example.com/").then(dom => {
  // ... expect(dom.....)
});    INSIDE MY TEST FUNCTION

Comment: I need it better like a constant so I can load it once in my test file

Comment: The `dom` provided in the `.then` handler is exactly the same `dom` as provided when you do `const dom = new JSDOM...`. You are having trouble with writing an asynchronous test in your test framework. I don't know what test framework you are using, and, anyhow, how to write asynchronous tests is really orthogonal to how to get JSDOM to load HTML from a file. You should ask another question about how to write synchronous tests for your framework. You *could* do `fs.readFileSync` but, sooner or later, you are going to need to write asynchronous tests. Might as well learn early.

Comment: This doesn´work my friend, but I see it exists in teh doc of jsdom so I accepted it, cause maybe I implemented it wrong. Now the test passes when it shouldn´t too, that means it doesnt consider the file at all.

Comment: It does work. I tried it and had no issue. When you are testing asynchronous code, like you have here, a test that passes when it should fail is *very often* an indication that your framework is not actually waiting for the test code to run before calling it successful. In Mocha, (and I think Jasmine too), you'd have to return the promise to the test framework or call a callback provided by the framework.